# Github actions build before tests (actions order)

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have three github actions workflows - Build, Tests, Mypy. I wanna build docker image in Build and after this run Tests and Mypy in container from this image. I wanna do this on every commit

Now I do it like that:

```
name: Mypy

on: 
  workflow_run:
    workflows: "Build"
    types:
    - completed

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Mypy
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Run mypy
      run: docker compose run mailing_service mypy src/ --strict
```

But with this way Tests and Mypy is not commit checkers and when Tests or Mypy fails, commit checks passed anyway.
How can I run Mypy and Tests after Build so if Mypy or Tests fails - commit checking fails?

Build:

```
name: Build
on:
  - push

jobs:
  docker_publish:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-20.04"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build . --tag ghcr.io/kryseyt/mailing_service

      - name: Login to ghcr
        run: echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Push image
        run: docker push ghcr.io/kryseyt/mailing_service:latest
```

Tests:

```
name: Tests

on: 
  workflow_run:
    workflows: "Build"
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      OS: ubuntu-latest
      PYTHON: '3.11'
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Run tests
      run: docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f tests.yml up --abort-on-container-exit
      
    - name: Copy coverage data from containerI
      run: docker compose cp mailing_service:/mailing_service/coverage.xml ./

    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
      with:
        directory: ./
        env_vars: OS,PYTHON
        fail_ci_if_error: true
        files: ./coverage.xml
        flags: unit-tests
        name: codecov-umbrella
        path_to_write_report: ./coverage/codecov_report.txt
        verbose: true
```

Comment: An option could be to convert your 3 workflows to reusable workflows, and gather all of them in jobs in the same workflow (triggered by your commits). With the Tests and Mypy jobs depending on the Build job.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct your `Mypy` and `Tests` to run on [`workflow_call`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_call) instead of `workflow_run`, then you can have all of them in one workflow file in which you can set a dependency with [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

See more on [reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

For your case you would have `.github/workflows/test.yaml`:

```
name: Tests

on: 
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...
```

And `.github/workflows/my-py.yaml`:

```
name: Mypy

on: 
  workflow_run:
    workflows: "Build"
    types:
    - completed

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Mypy
    ...
```

Then in your main workflow file, you'd have something like:

```
name: Build
on:
  - push

jobs:
  docker_publish:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-20.04"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build . --tag ghcr.io/kryseyt/mailing_service

      - name: Login to ghcr
        run: echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Push image
        run: docker push ghcr.io/kryseyt/mailing_service:latest

  myPy:
    needs: docker_publish
    uses: ./github/workflows/my-py.yaml
  tests:
    needs: docker_publish
    uses: ./github/workflows/test.yaml
```